# How two bind data to Linechart in highcharts in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts, linechart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bind data to line chart in highcharts in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177198/how-to-bind-data-to-line-chart-in-highcharts-in-mvc3)

i have two procedure's in my entity frame work..and method to return data as json..how do i call these two procedure in my single method where i have to return these two procedures as a single json object .....and return this data to my .$getJson method in my jquery...can any tell me how to do this and that returned data should be binded to Linechart of highcharts as two separate lines   cana ny one tell me how can i acheive this

```
   public ActionResult LoggedBugs()
    {
        return View();  
    }

    public JsonResult CreatedBugs()
    {
        int year;
        int month;
        int projectid;
        year=2012;
        month=8;
        projectid=16;
        var loggedbugs = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<LoggedBugs>("LoggedBugs @Year,@Month,@ProjectID", new SqlParameter("@Year", year), new SqlParameter("@Month", month), new SqlParameter("@ProjectID", projectid)).ToList();
        var ClosedBugs= db.ExecuteStoreQuery<ClosedBugs>("ClosedBugs @Year,@Month,@ProjectID", new SqlParameter("@Year", year), new SqlParameter("@Month", month), new SqlParameter("@ProjectID", projectid)).ToList();
        return Json(loggedbugs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

i want to return loggedbugs and Closedbugs as json object to my view and from there i have to bind this data to Linechart...where loggedbugs  should have one line and Closedbugs  should have other line ....expecting help here

Answer (score 0):

As always in an MVC application, start by defining a view model that will contain the information that your view requires (in your case that would be the list of logged and closed bugs):

```
public class BugsViewModel
{
    public string IEnumerable<LoggedBugs> LoggedBugs { get; set; }
    public string IEnumerable<ClosedBugs> ClosedBugs { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action populate this view model that will be passed to the view:

```
public ActionResult CreatedBugs()
{
    var year = 2012;
    var month = 8;
    var projectid = 16;
    var loggedbugs = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<LoggedBugs>("LoggedBugs @Year,@Month,@ProjectID", new SqlParameter("@Year", year), new SqlParameter("@Month", month), new SqlParameter("@ProjectID", projectid)).ToList();
    var closedBugs = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<ClosedBugs>("ClosedBugs @Year,@Month,@ProjectID", new SqlParameter("@Year", year), new SqlParameter("@Month", month), new SqlParameter("@ProjectID", projectid)).ToList();
    var model = new BugsViewModel
    {
        LoggedBugs = loggedBugs,
        ClosedBugs = closedBug
    };
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: then how will i show this data in my line chart..how do i manipulate this data to show in my line chart..where LoggedBugs  should have a separate line and ClosedBugs  should have a separate line